# From Github to Existing Android project

Tags: android, github, android-widget

I am new to android development, so sorry if the question is not clear.
I want to use the widget "number-picker" it can be found on Github in this [link](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/tree/master/library). I know there is a way to import the git project to eclipse, but what I would like to do is to add it to my project that is already exist. I have tried manually add the classes and all included folders to that widget to my project, the problem is  there is no xml file that explains how to add this number-picker element to the activity. 
Here is how I did it:
1. added the Scroller and the NumberPicker classes to the src folder under the project package.
2. added the drawable xmls, valuse and images.
3. added the jar file to Android Dependencies folder.
4. have added this to the activity xml file:

```
<com.example.mathgame.NumberPicker
android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and this to the main activity class:

```
package com.example.mathgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.example.mathgame.NumberPicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        np.setMaxValue(24);
        np.setMinValue(1);
        np.setFocusable(true);

        np.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    }


}
```

when I run the app this is my exception from the logCat:

```
12-14 20:23:26.283: E/AndroidRuntime(29792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 20:23:26.283: E/AndroidRuntime(29792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathgame/com.example.mathgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.NumberPicker cannot be cast to com.example.mathgame.NumberPicker
```

I would like to know what is the wright way to work with imported github projects and what should I do to fix this one. Thanks!!!

---

I found why the app crashed. it was because of number_picker.xml file, I have changed to com.example.mathgame.NumberPicker in some places. Now the app starts but the number picker looks odd (I have the button and some element near it). Here how it looks now:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/np_increment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?attr/numberPickerUpButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/np_number_picker_increment_button" />

    <view class="com.example.mathgame.NumberPicker$CustomEditText"
        android:id="@+id/np_numberpicker_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?attr/numberPickerInputTextStyle" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/np_decrement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?attr/numberPickerDownButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/np_number_picker_decrement_button" />

</merge>
```

Comment: chave you tried  as `com.example.mathgame.NumberPicker np = (com.example.mathgame.NumberPicke) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);`

Comment: If you are certain you do not have `import android.widget.NumberPicker;` in MainActivity, try cleaning your project.

Comment: I have edited the question after some fixes

Comment: @VladIoffe : currently how you are adding this project i your project?

Comment: @VladIoffe : first import [this](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/tree/master/library) project in your workspace from File->import operation in eclipse .after that right click on your own project and select properties . from properties select Android option and after selection android an popup window appear scroll down to bottom on this window where you can see add library option

Comment: import it as android project?

Answer (score 1):

It's a library project.So you can add this project directally in your android proect.
Just Import a Library project.
Then goto the project properties->android->scroll down 
add library project.
After all use this library classes for create object.

Comment: can you explain how do I add this library project to my project?

Comment: Going to the project properties->android->scroll down  add seen add  library project